# How to change vertex font size in TreeGraph?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I tried to change vertex label font size by the following code

```
g = TreeGraph[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 24 -> 30, 
   24 -> 50, 40 -> 55, 40 -> 45}, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
      RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
      Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

which turns out not working.  I checked the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeGraph.html), but was not able to find a solution.  Anyone knows what is the correct way to change font size in TreeGraph?  Thank you!

Comment: `VertexStyle -> Directive[FontSize ->14]` or `VertexStyle -> 14`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TreeGraph[
      {11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 
       24 -> 30, 24 -> 50, 40 -> 55, 40 -> 45},
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
     RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
     Text[Style[#2, 22, Red], #1]} &)]
```

[image]